# Visual Studio 2017 macros show empty on build but not in macro selector

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

When I add a post build event to my project and try to use a macro in the Edit Post-Build ... section it shows the value of each  macro

[image: post build events]

However when the build runs the value show blank

the following was generated using  echo "The project path is:" $(ProjectPath) "end of path"

[image: build output]

any macro value I use seems to come up null

I am using the following csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Client</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Client</PackageId>
    <PackageTags>pkgname</PackageTags>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      echo on
      echo "The project path is:" $(ProjectPath) "end of path"
      dotnet pack $(ProjectPath)
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NoSQL" Version="1.0.4.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have tried manually editing the csproj to no avail. a full path to the csproj in the post build event does work.

I have confirmed that this occurs on multiple machines running VS/15.0.0+26228.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an open issue for VS 2017
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25206/build-events-window-strips-out-macros-unce-saved.html

Comment: I've created a project that demonstrates the issue:
https://github.com/BalassaMarton/VS2017Issues/tree/master/BuildEventMacrosAreEmpty

Comment: circa 2021: the issue still there

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a bug with the macro environment variables like `$(ConfigurationName)` being ignored, at least in **Visual Studio 2017 ver. 15.9.11**

This worked for me:
Specify your script in a `<Target Name=...>` element in the project file (.vbproj)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="PostBuild" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <!-- For " use &quot; -->
        <Exec Command="
            if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
                echo Upload Debug files:
                cmd /c &quot;S:\My Script\Debug_upload.cmd&quot;
            )
            if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
                echo Upload Release files:
                cmd /c &quot;S:\My Script\Release_upload.cmd&quot;
            )"/>
    </Target>
    ...
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Comment: This worked for me, though I needed to use Name="PreBuild" and BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" in order to get a command to run before the project is built.

Comment: I can also confirm that this is an issue in Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.8.5 but seems to have been fixed in Visual Studio 2019.